# Flask - How to require login only for post requests

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-login

I'm working in Flask and I want to allow users to enter information into a form without logging in but be required to login if they submit the form. After logging in, it should be as though a user just submitted the form (they shouldn't have to re-enter any information).

To store their information, I've used sessions like this. It works well:

```
if request.method == "POST":

    if "arg1" not in session.keys() and "arg2" not in session.keys():
            session["arg1"] = request.form.get('arg1')
            session["arg2"] = request.form.get('arg2')
```

However, I'm having trouble with the login required part. I know I can use @login_required on the whole route but I just want @login_required to apply if the request is a post method. I've tried simply adding @login_required after checking if the method is a post request but it doesn't work.

My login route looks like this:

```
@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():

    #log user in

    return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for('index'))
```

It seems as though I need two things.

1: To apply @login_required solely to a post request.

2: To have request.args.get("next") call a post request, not get request

How could I go about doing these two things and achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Break out your routes. 1 for GET and 1 for POST

```
@app.route("/login", methods = ["GET"])
def get_login():
    return stuff


@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def post_login():
    return stuff
```

There are a couple patterns that could be used here but this one is the most straight forward.

Comment: Thank you! You mean I should break up the route that contains the form, not the login route right? That seems to solve the first step, but now how can I make `redirect(request.args.get("next"))` a POST request? I know with url_for I could simply add `code = 307` as an argument but can that be done without using `url_for?` Thank you so much!